# Is this sentence right?

Tags: grammar

I poped the movies on the player,then we were crying,laughing and chilling about the movies almost one night.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would write:

"I popped the movies on the player and we cried, laughed and chilled almost the whole night". The second mention of the movies is redundant because you've established at the start of the sentence that you're writing about the movies, so we can safely assume it's the movies which produced the diverse range of reactions. Sounds like a good night!